# Get notified of answers to a question?

Tags: support

Is there a way to say "I want to get an email update when an answer is posted to this question" (that is, to someone else's question)? Right now, the only thing I can see to do is to tag it as a favorite so it's easy to check back now and again.

Comment: May be duplicate of [this](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1276/3066).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, there is not a way to have SE let you know by email immediately when an answer is posted to a question, but I have written (not really super proud of this yet but it works) a grep tool where you can paste the URL to the question, the frequency that you want *Mathematica* to check, and the number of times you want *Mathematica* to keep checking. Although it aborts well on discovery of a new answer, as well as manually, it seems sort of trashy to me to not have a nicer abort button than "Evaluation->Abort Evaluation", or "Alt +".

The grep does export then import to and from a flat file on your default local.

Anyway, here is my code, feel free to improve:

Set `link` to the URL of the post.

Set `cnum` to the current number of answers (default 0).

Set `checktimer` to the frequency that you wish to probe this site in seconds (careful here, don't slam SE).

Set `stopcheck` to the number of times you you wish to probe.

All is currently set to every 5 minutes (300 seconds) for 1 hour.

```
grep[file_, patt_] := 
With[{data = Import[file, "Lines"]}, 
Pick[Transpose[{Range[Length[data]], data}], 
StringFreeQ[data, patt], False]]

link = "http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/get-notified-of-answers-to-a-question";
cnum = 0; (*current number of posts*)
checktimer = 300; (*check every number of seconds*)
stopcheck = 12;(*stop the loop after stop multiplied by checktimer seconds*)
```

The `grep` function should seem pretty clear, I used it in the past scraping data from web sites (probably ripped it off somewhere long ago).

Here is the implementation:

```
For[i = 1, i <= stopcheck, i++,
Pause[checktimer];(*seconds*)
Export["segrep.txt", Import[link, "Plaintext"]];
If[Length[grep["segrep.txt", {"improve this answer"}]] > cnum,
SendMail[
"To" -> "your-inbound-email@icloud.com",
"Subject" -> "Stackexchange!",
"Body" -> "You have a new Mathematica answer on stackexchange!",
"From" -> "your-outbound-email@gmail.com",
"Server" -> "smtp.gmail.com",
"UserName" -> "your-outbound-email@gmail.com",
"Password" -> "your-outbound-password",(*<<<---Needs Password, else add in prompt*)
"PortNumber" -> 587,
"EncryptionProtocol" -> "StartTLS"];
Abort[];
]
]
```

You clearly need to put your two email addresses and password inside the quotes correctly. If you use a gmail outbound to your phone email push, then the rest will probably work as is (otherwise alter).

Change the URL, and change `checktimer` and `cnum` to some small numbers for your test. Don't slam the site.

P.S. The hardest part of this was finding the distinguishing difference between a question with n versus n+1 answers in any SE community. It turned out that grepping "improve this answer" did the trick.

On to the final test...

Comment: Thanks. I guess that's best practice as of now...but really not optimal!